# Denesting Radicals with two different radicands

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

After thinking some time about denesting radicals, I wondered if it was possible to denest a radical in the form $\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{\alpha}+\sqrt[c]{\beta}}$

I thought about rewriting the inside to a power equal to that of $a$. For example: $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{13}+3\sqrt[3]{4}}=x\sqrt[3]{13}+y\sqrt[3]{4}$. And cubing both sides would give you a Polynomial. Combining terms would give you $x$ and $y$ etc. But I thought that the process would take too long and probably become tedious, especially when $a=10$ or maybe even $50$.

So at this point, I have no idea... anything (including ideas/suggestions) is welcome.

Comment: Even for your example, the equations you have to solve are nasty.

Comment: Yes. I acknowledge that they are nasty (like all the time).

Comment: $\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{13}+3\sqrt[3]{4}}=\frac {1}{3}\left(\sqrt[3]{169}+\sqrt[3]{52}-\sqrt[3]{2}\right)$